# How can I start the server with the code configuration rather than the XML file configuration?

Tags: .net, orleans

I want to start the server with the code configuration rather than the XML file configuration, but the silo server cannot start without calling the LoadOrleansConfig method.

```
string providerName = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient";
string mysqlConnString = "mysqlConnString";

var config = new ClusterConfiguration();
config.Globals.DeploymentId = "OrleansTest";
config.Globals.AdoInvariant = providerName;
config.Globals.DataConnectionString = mysqlConnString;

config.Globals.LivenessType = LivenessProviderType.Custom;
config.Globals.ReminderServiceType = ReminderServiceProviderType.Custom;
config.Globals.MembershipTableAssembly = "OrleansSQLUtils";
config.Globals.ReminderTableAssembly = "OrleansSQLUtils";

config.Defaults.HostNameOrIPAddress = "localhost";
config.Defaults.Port = 11111;
config.Defaults.ProxyGatewayEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 30000);

using (var host = new SiloHost("Default"))
{
    host.Config = config;
    host.InitializeOrleansSilo();
    var result = host.StartOrleansSilo();
    Console.WriteLine("server startup {0}", result ? "successful" : "failure");
    Console.ReadLine();
    host.StopOrleansSilo();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to load the config from a file.
Instead of doing `host.Config = config;` pass the config via the constructor:
https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/blob/master/src/OrleansRuntime/Silo/SiloHost.cs#L97

Answer (score 0):

By default, starting the silo will swallow any exceptions. Start it like this and you'll get a bit more info:

```
var result = host.StartOrleansSilo(catchExceptions: false);
```

In this case, you get:

> "Cannot start silo Default due to prior initialization error"

That's nothing you didn't already know. To fix the problem, set up your SiloHost like this:

```
using (var host = new SiloHost("Default", config))
```